# Log Transforming variables already in percentage

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear-model, logarithm, percentage

I'm running a regression analysis and I'd like to know if log transforming a percentage value is ok. My y-values are already in percentages and my x-values in absolute numbers. But I'd like to know by how much % y changes with respect to 1% change in x. Is it okay that I log transform my y-values along with my x-values?

Comment: Assuming that you have no zeros, the best answer to this is to plot percent versus log x and log percent versus log x and think which makes more sense. (Note: in some cases you need more logit (percent / 100.)